# Summing values of positive or negative "streaks"

Tags: r

I am working with data in R as pictured below looking at weekly weight changes.

| ID | Week | Weight Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | -0.5 |
| 1 | 2 | -0.2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 5 | -0.5 |
| 2 | 1 | -0.2 |
| 2 | 2 | -0.2 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 4 | -0.5 |
| 2 | 5 | -0.3 |

dput is

```
df <- tibble(
  ID = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
  Week = rep(1:5,2),
  WeightChange = c(-0.5,-0.2,1,
                   0.5,-0.5,-0.2,-0.2,
                   0.6,-0.5,-0.3)
  )
)
```

I am interested in trying to calculate the amount of weight lost or gained in "streaks" within each individual and the number of weeks of each streak, similar to the table below. My R skills are pretty basic, so I'm not exactly sure where to even start. The actual dataset has about 40 weeks of data for around 75 participants. Any help would be much appreciated.

| ID | Streak Length | Weight Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | -0.7 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.5 |
| 1 | 1 | -0.5 |
| 2 | 2 | -0.4 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.6 |
| 2 | 2 | -0.8 |

Comment: PLease use the code rather than the tables. I added them and someone posted it in the answer as well, but doing that in the question makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1) data.table/dplyr** Grouping by ID and streak (computed using rleid of the sign), summarize the result and drop streak which we no longer need.  rleid is the only function from data.table used.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(ID, streak = rleid(sign(`Weight Change`))) %>%
  summarize(`Streak Length` = n(), `Weight Change` = sum(`Weight Change`), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-streak)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID `Streak Length` `Weight Change`
  <int>           <int>           <dbl>
1     1               2            -0.7
2     1               2             1.5
3     1               1            -0.5
4     2               2            -0.4
5     2               1             0.6
6     2               2            -0.8
```

**2) collapse/magrittr** We could alternately use the collapse package with magrittr.  groupid is similar to rleid in data.table.

```
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)

dat %>%
  tfm(streak = groupid(sign(`Weight Change`)), `Streak Length` = 1) %>%
  collap(~ ID + streak, fsum, cols = c("Weight Change", "Streak Length")) %>%
  slt(-streak)
```

giving:

```
  ID Weight Change Streak Length
1  1          -0.7             2
2  1           1.5             2
3  1          -0.5             1
4  2          -0.4             2
5  2           0.6             1
6  2          -0.8             2
```

**3) data.table** Using data.table only we have:

```
as.data.table(dat)[, .(`Streak Length` = .N, `Weight Change` = sum(`Weight Change`)), 
  by = .(ID, rleid(sign(`Weight Change`)))][, -2]
```

giving:

```
   ID Streak Length Weight Change
1:  1             2          -0.7
2:  1             2           1.5
3:  1             1          -0.5
4:  2             2          -0.4
5:  2             1           0.6
6:  2             2          -0.8
```

### Note

```
dat <- 
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), `Weight Change` = c(-0.5, 
    -0.2, 1, 0.5, -0.5, -0.2, -0.2, 0.6, -0.5, -0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Used the first solution and it worked! Thanks so much - this is incredibly helpful

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'ID Week    WeightChange
1   1   -0.5
1   2   -0.2
1   3   1
1   4   0.5
1   5   -0.5
2   1   -0.2
2   2   -0.2
2   3   0.6
2   4   -0.5
2   5   -0.3', header = T)

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>% group_by(ID, running_streak = rleid(WeightChange > 0)) %>%
  summarise(running_streak = n(),
            WeightChange = sum(WeightChange), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      ID running_streak WeightChange
#>   <int>          <int>        <dbl>
#> 1     1              2         -0.7
#> 2     1              2          1.5
#> 3     1              1         -0.5
#> 4     2              2         -0.4
#> 5     2              1          0.6
#> 6     2              2         -0.8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Since nearly a similar answer has been posted simultaneously, alternative with baseR `rle` i.e. without using `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID, running_streak = with(rle(WeightChange > 0), rep(seq_len(length(lengths)), lengths))) %>%
  summarise(running_streak = n(),
            WeightChange = sum(WeightChange), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      ID running_streak WeightChange
#>   <int>          <int>        <dbl>
#> 1     1              2         -0.7
#> 2     1              2          1.5
#> 3     1              1         -0.5
#> 4     2              2         -0.4
#> 5     2              1          0.6
#> 6     2              2         -0.8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>